# Send separate requests instead of one whole in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

I want to modify this function to send these two file ids in the separate requests:

```
return this.upload(myForm).pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(res => {
    body.user.profilePic = res.data.profilePic;
    body.user.coverPic = res.data.coverPic;

    return this.http.post<IRresponse<object>>(environment.api + EndPoint.CreateUser, body);
})
);
```

Should I use flatmap?

Answer (score 1):

You can do separate requests from one pipe like that:

```
return this.upload(myForm).pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(res => {
    body.user.profilePic = res.data.profilePic;
    body.user.coverPic = res.data.coverPic;

    return [
      this.http.post<IRresponse<object>>(environment.api + EndPoint.CreateUser, body),
      this.http.post<IRresponse<object>>(environment.api + EndPoint.CreateUser, body),
    ]
  }),
  mergeAll(),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The right operator depends on whether you want to send the two request in parallel or consecutively.

If you already have `take(1)` then you can use both `switchMap` or `mergeMap` because it will always emit only once and thus it doesn't matter in this case.

Sending requests in parallel:

```
return this.upload(myForm).pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(res => {
    ...
    return forkJoin([
      this.http.post<IRresponse<object>>(environment.api + EndPoint.CreateUser, body),
      this.http.post<IRresponse<object>>(environment.api + EndPoint.CreateUser, body),
    ]);
  }),
);
```

Sending requests in sequence:

```
return this.upload(myForm).pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(res => {
    ...
    return concat(
      this.http.post<IRresponse<object>>(environment.api + EndPoint.CreateUser, body),
      this.http.post<IRresponse<object>>(environment.api + EndPoint.CreateUser, body),
    );
  }),
);
```